# How to make an angular child component be rendered on top of everything else

Tags: javascript, angular, overlay, z-index, angular-cdk

I have an Angular component with a child component. I need the child component to be rendered on top of everything on the page, including the parent's components siblings (think like a floating menu). The parent component has a service provided in it (not provided in root, so each of these components gets their own instance of the service). The child component will have that service injected. I tried changing the z-index but it doesn't work because the child component is within its parent which is below its sibling divs. I tried using Angular Cdk's Overlay module but the service injector wont work then. Any suggestions or do I need to do a large refactor?

Comment: Without any code that you are using it's hard to see the problem you're having and we'd likely be stabbing in the dark. You've done a good job of explaining what you're doing, but not any specific things you've tried or any particular problems you are facing after some of your own troubleshooting. Adding some more details to your question will definitely improve it and we should be able to help you out better.

Answer (score 0):

1. the absolute positioning inside relative will help you:
   https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/
2. the problem is make a padding on the height of this child component.
   But I think it can be managed